# Next.js use getStaticProps for mdx pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I use `getStaticProps` for .mdx pages in Next.js? The return value of `getStaticProps` should be sent to all React components that get rendered in my MDX file.

Comment: Also interested in this... @hoan did you discover how to do it?

Comment: @AralRoca check this out: https://noahfleischmann.com/blog/next-image-optimization. Specifically the part about `enhanced-file-loader`. Perhaps not quite what you want, but it solved my issue.